# How should I reconnect my light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I took my ceiling light down to paint it and when I put it back I connected the white wire to the 2 white wires in the pic. I connected the black wire to the black bundle in the pic. Now the light is on all the time no matter the switch position. I can't figure it out. I don't have a meter.

[image]

Comment: I see red in there too. Is this a 3 way configuration ( 2 wall switches? )

Answer (score 2):

Your specific wiring is not entirely clear from your picture but here is the number one mistake novices make:

In most older homes the switch loop comes down from the light fixture to the switch and then back up to feed the light. At the time your house was built the switch location did not require a neutral. So you probably only have a 2 wire cable going to the switch and as the Electrical Code requires, the white wire feeds the switch hot and the return from the switch back to the light is a black wire. The white wire to the switch is supposed to be re-identified a different color. Usually it just gets black tape put on it but often it was not properly re-identified at all. (Probably the case at your place)

So, what this means is that you have reconnected your light to the hot black from the panel and the neutral white back to the panel. So your light is on all the time as long as the breaker is on. If you connected the white and black from the switch to these bundles then when you flip the switch it should trip the breaker.

You need to identify which cable goes to the switch. The white wire in that cable should be taped black and connected to the black bundle. Then the black wire coming back from the switch goes to the black on the light. The white on the light goes to the white of the cable feeding the box from the panel.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to figure it out. I appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Insulate the black bundle well.  Stuff it back in the box.  Hook you light to the other two, wire to wire. Happy Thanksgiving. P.

Answer (score 0):

Given the number of wires in that box, it's clear you also have power rolling through there on the way to somewhere else.  That is to say, this box is also being used as a junction box for other loads.

Cables have generally 2 colors of wire: black and white.  They can be assigned to different purposes, but Neutral if present must be the white.  Therefore usually, black is *always-hot* and white is neutral.

Almost certainly, your  big clump of blacks and whites are always-hot and neutral.  That was easy.

Your lamp needs neutral and it looks like one of those bared wires is pigtailed off the neutral bundle.  That's for the lamp.  That was also eqsy.

The lamp needs one more wire (besides ground): switched-hot.  Where does it get that? A switch loop, which is one cable to the switch.  Its wire functions are hot and switched-hot.  a switch loop installed post-2011 also requires a neutral and uses black-white-red wires.   Yours is probably not.

In that case it will have the same black-white cable, so the colors won't match the function.  White has to be hot or switched-hot.  If white goes into a bundle of blacks, that makes it easy to tell.  If not, switched-hot will be white. *Don't put it in the neutral bundle*.

If you had just found it like the picture, I would say that one white is neutral and the other white was switched-hot.  They both have seen wire nuts, I would say those are your lamp wires.

The one to the white bundle is actual neutral.

*Code now requires "hot" white wires be marked by wrapping with tape etc.*